# How to add values of two rows as a value to another column in sql developer(oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table like this:

```
S.No | (C1) |  (C2)  | (C3) | 
-----------------------------------------------
1    |  A   |   10    |  10  | (I want 10 here)
-----------------------------------------------
2    |  B   |   20    |  0   | (I want 30 here)
-----------------------------------------------
3    |  C   |   30    |  0   | (I want 60 here)
-----------------------------------------------
4    |  D   |   40    |  0   | (I want 100 here)
-----------------------------------------------
```

How can I write ORACLE Query for this?

Comment: use `SUM(c2) OVER ( ORDER BY sno) as c3`

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want window functions.  If you want a `select`:

```
select t.*, sum(c2) over (partition by s_no) as c3
from t;
```

If you want to modify the data, this logic is hard to put into an `update`.  One method if your data is not large is to use a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set c3 = (select sum(t2.c3) from t t2 where t2.s_no <= t2.s_no);
```

For larger data, you would want to use `merge`, but I'm not sure if that is a consideration.